# Получение значений отмеченных чекбоксов

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Получаю из реестра список установленных программ в `ListView`. Чекбоксами отмечаются нужные программы. Как к примеру вывести значения выделенных чекбоксов (названий программ) и записать все это в массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо ищем в `Items` выбранные, к примеру, делаете проверку, что есть выбранные и затем берете их по условию `Checked`:

```
if (listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(x => x.Checked)) 
{
   // делаете то, что нужно
   var lst = listView1.Items
       .Cast<ListViewItem>()
       .Where(x => x.Checked)
       .Select(li => li.Text)
       .ToList(); 
   // к примеру список строк получите (сделайте ToArray() - вот Вам массив строк)
   var arr = listView1.Items
       .Cast<ListViewItem>()
       .Where(x => x.Checked)
       .Select(li => li.Text)
       .ToArray(); 
   // либо вместо Text можете взять Name, вообще то, что Вам нужно берите 
   // и т.д. ...
}
```

Либо просто в готовом [`CheckedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) получаем выбранные так:

```
var lstChecked = new List<string>();
for (int index = 0; index < listView1.CheckedItems.Count; index++)
{
    lstChecked.Add(listView1.CheckedItems[index].Text); 
}
var arrChecked = lstChecked.ToArray(); // в массив
```

или вот так:

```
var arrCh = listView1.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(li => li.Text).ToArray();
```

Два способа на Ваш вкус, и тот и тот удобны, но я отдаю предпочтение второму - `CheckedItems`.

---

Что получается в результате. Выбираем элементы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрим в отладке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все работает, проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: Он выводит только 1 чекбокс, а если их несколько?

Comment: @g431k, что значит выводит только один чекбокс? Насколько я понял у  Вас `listView`, в котором свойство `CheckBoxes` установлено в `True`, уточните свой вопрос

Comment: Прошу прощения, не правильно сформулировал. Выбрано несколько чекбоксов, а значение он выводит только одного

Comment: @g431k, весь код, который я приложил - проверил, у меня выводит все выбранные, приложил скриншоты. Покажите в отладке, что делаете и что не получается?

Comment: Еще раз прошу прощения, все работает, спасибо